# Password TextBox in Registration form has some value on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a Registration form and following is the design code of Password and Confirm password field

```
<tr>
    <td class="style14">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" Width="150px" EnableTheming="True" 
                TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="style23">
        <asp:Label ID="lblCnfPass" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCnfPass" runat="server" Width="150px" TextMode="Password" 
                    CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Paswword doesnot Match" ValidationGroup="register"  ControlToCompare="txtCnfPass" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtPass">Paswword doesnot Match</asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is when I run the page the password textbox is filled with some values, as [in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtJPx.png). How do I remove that? One more point is that when I changed TextMode property from password to singleline then there was no such problem!

Comment: try to put empty text in it, also try to change the "autocomplete" property.

Comment: @user1947927 your definitely not populating the text box somewhere?

Comment: @james please explain your answer

Comment: @user1947927 you confirm that on page load you not fill any text in password textbox

Comment: @Prashant16 dude page load is just blank and there is no code for Password TextBox

Comment: ..perhaps your browser is remembering the content? Tried emptying your cache completely? (passwords, etc)?

Comment: I have cleared browser's cookie and history but problem remains. One thing is the problem is not with Internet explorer and Chrome but on Mozillla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem basically is due to Mozilla Firefox browser. Mozilla Firefox Password Manager places the password into the last input field preceding the stored input field. Just place a hidden dummy TextBox (or input) field inside  Authentication control will precedes your password input field.
For more details read the description here
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox%3aPassword_Manager

Answer (score 1):

I think the value is coming from the Autofill feature of your browser. Clear the browser history including saved passwords and try again. 
Ashik

Comment: I have cleared browser's cookie and history but problem remains. One thing is the problem is not with Internet explorer and Chrome but on Mozillla

Comment: Set this property on the txtPass control. autocomplete="off"

Comment: problem remains. When i decode the password on page source the text was gfgfg and when i ctrl+f on page to search whether i have written this text by mistake then it didnot found anything

Comment: and when i change TextMode property from password to singleline there was no such problem then

Comment: Change the Id of txtPass and set name="somename" and see what happens, it seems a bug in Mozilla.... Have a look here..  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=362576